# VB.NET not copying a folder to new destination

Tags: vb.net, directory

So I want to copy the folder at the end, But, for some reason, it doesn't copy it. I do not get an error message, so the code doesn't have errors, it's just incorrect.

```
    Dim Log As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss"))
    Process.Start("CMD", "/c robocopy.exe " & Source & " " & Destination & " /log:C:\Backup\log_" & Log & ".txt ")



    Dim Copy2 As String = ("Backup_" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss"))


    Dim Destination2 As String
    Destination2 = Destination
    Dim copy4 As String = Destination2.Substring(0, Destination2.LastIndexOf("\"))
    Dim Copy3 As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(copy4, Copy2)
    FileIO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(Copy3)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveDirectory(Destination, Copy3, True)
    MsgBox("Backup ist vollendet!")
```

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: At which line do you get an error ? What does the error say ?

Comment: `[...] why this isn't working?` Elaborate `isn´t working`.

Comment: @Alex B. Why this dosnt work.. its early in the morning...

Comment: I did not mean the grammar. Please elaborate what `does not work` means. Is there a compile error, an exception during runtime, no error at all but expected result differs from actual result, ...?

Comment: Does your code reach the `MsgBox`? If so, this will at least tell you that all of the code is executing. Put in a breakpoint, step through the code, and check all of your variables have the correct values, just as a starting point.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sometimes I wish there was a button for *us* which would automatically post your comment!

Comment: @Verdolino: ;-) Here's the bookmarklet I use: http://pastie.org/10955959

Answer (score 0):

did you try to end the Process, befor accessing the just copied data ? 
Try  :

> process.kill

Comment: is it possible, to wait until the copy process ended?

Comment: you can ask the process if it's ended. 
For this you can use process.hasexited ,but I don't know how robocopy will behave on this / I don't know it will tell if it has exited.

Comment: Have a look at Process.WaitforExit